# Saving last 4 characters of a string in android

Tags: java, android, string

Simple one this morning, but causing me issues and can't seem to find any code out there. I have created a hex representation of a number, and wish to now save the last 4 characters of the hex string to then convert back to an integer.

The code that converts is shown below:

```
int in2 = new Integer(mycard.resourceid.toString());
String hex = Integer.toHexString(in2);
```

If someone could nudge me in the right direction I would be most appreciative.

```
int in3 = new Integer(hex.length());
int in4 = new Integer (in3 - 4);
String mystring = hex.subString(in4, in3);
```

Comment: Quick note on code formatting: indenting by 4 characters (or using the `{}` button in the editor) is sufficient to format your code. If you indent it by many multiples of 4, it ends up half-way across the page, and eventually triggers a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Sorry about that, it kept the indent from the code itself, fixed it now. Don't suppose you can see how that is using a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want a nudge, look for the `substring` method of the `String` class.

EDIT: Some sample code in response to OP followup:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Integer in2 = 897387483;
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(in2);
        System.out.println(hex);
        System.out.println(hex.substring(hex.length()-4, hex.length()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a small problem with it saying that I am trying to use strings. Updating original, can't see how I am using strings.

Comment: @chris I've added a sample piece of code to the answer.  It runs fine as is.  See if you can compare it to what you have. I think you mis-capitalized `substring`.

Comment: Marvelous - thank you - and once again a rookie error from myself!

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = mycard.resourcdeid.toString();
int in2 = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.length() - 4, s.length());
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I am an android nooby and want to understand why my error is there. The hex characters are 9f8f etc that I wish to save, wouldn't saving as an int not cause errors with characters like f?

Comment: So... don't parse it as an int. I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

(new Integer(intValueYouLikeToConvert & 0xffff)).toHexString() shall do the trick

All previous examples do not take in account, that resulting string may be shorter than 4 characters

Answer (score 0):

lets suppose your hex string is: String hex = oxFFFFFF
take substring hex = hex.subString(2);

Answer (score 0):

To remove last 4 character, Please try this once

```
yourString.substring(0, yourString.length() - 4) ;
```

For keep only last 4 character

```
yourString.substring(yourString.length() - 4, yourString.length()) ;
```